# Showing hidden on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I want to show the contents using bootstrap modal. Email, gender and status are hidden and will be visible only if I click on the view more button. I want these to be shown using bootstrap modal.

```
let table;

const show = (data) => {
  table.innerHTML = data
    .map(({id,name,email, gender,status}) => `<tr>
      <td> ${name}</td>
      <td> <button class="more" data-id="${id}">View More</button></td>
      <td hidden id="email">${email}</td>
      <td hidden id="gender">${gender}</td>
      <td hidden id="status">${status}</td>
      </tr>`)
    .join("");
};

const load = () => {
  fetch("https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users")
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(show);
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  table = document.getElementById('table');
  table.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
    if (!tgt) return;
    tgt.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => td.hidden = false);
  })

  load();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap 5 as version was not stated. A lot of the example code referenced from [Bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/).

Approach here is to use one modal and swap data instead of one modal per record.

Replaced button in table with Bootstrap's version but added some of the record data in data attributes. Did this for quickness but a better alternative is to put your data in an object and reference it by `data-id`.

```js
// show() function
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary more"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
        data-id="${id}"
        data-name="${name}"
        data-email="${email}"
        data-gender="${gender}"
        data-status="${status}">
    View More
</button>
```

Add the bootstrap modal html

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div id="modalDynamicContent" class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally adding [show.bs.modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#events) event listener to listen when modal is opened from whichever `View More` button is clicked.

```js
const myModalEl = document.getElementById('exampleModal');
const myModalContent = document.getElementById('modalDynamicContent');

myModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
    // Button that triggered modal
    viewMoreButton = event.relatedTarget;
    
    // Get data
    id = viewMoreButton.dataset.id;
    email = viewMoreButton.dataset.email;
    gender = viewMoreButton.dataset.gender;
    status = viewMoreButton.dataset.status;

    myModalContent.innerHTML = `
          <p>
            Email: <span id="email">${email}</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            Gender: <span id="gender">${gender}</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            Status: <span id="status">${status}</span>
          </p>
    `
});
```

```js
let table;
const show = (data) => {
  //console.table(data);
  table.innerHTML = data
    .map(({id,name,email, gender,status}) => `<tr>
      <td> ${name}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary more"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
                data-id="${id}"
                data-name="${name}"
                data-email="${email}"
                data-gender="${gender}"
                data-status="${status}">
          View More
        </button>
      </td>
      <td hidden id="email">${email}</td>
      <td hidden id="gender">${gender}</td>
      <td hidden id="status">${status}</td>
      </tr>`)
    .join("");
};

const load = () => {
  fetch("https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users")
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(show);
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  table = document.getElementById('table');
  //table.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    //const tgt = e.target.closest("button");
    //if (!tgt) return;
    //tgt.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => td.hidden = false);
  //})
  load();
});

const myModalEl = document.getElementById('exampleModal');
const myModalContent = document.getElementById('modalDynamicContent');

myModalEl.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
    // Button that triggered modal
    viewMoreButton = event.relatedTarget;

    // Get data
    id = viewMoreButton.dataset.id;
    email = viewMoreButton.dataset.email;
    gender = viewMoreButton.dataset.gender;
    status = viewMoreButton.dataset.status;

    myModalContent.innerHTML = `
          <p>
            Email: <span id="email">${email}</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            Gender: <span id="gender">${gender}</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            Status: <span id="status">${status}</span>
          </p>
    `
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

<table id='table'>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div id="modalDynamicContent" class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```